# Kafka scalability if consuming from replica node

Tags: apache-kafka, high-availability

In a cluster scenario with data replication > 1, why is that we must always consume from a master/leader of a partition instead of being able to consume from a replica/follower node that contains a replica of this master node?

I understand the Kafka will always route the request to a master node(of that particular partition/topic) but doesn't this affect scalability (since all requests go to a single node)? Wouldnt it be better if we could read from any node containing the replica information and not necessarily the master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition leader replicas, from which you can write/read data, are evenly distributed among available brokers. Anyway, you may also want to leverage the "fetch from closest replica" functionality, which is described in [KIP-392](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-392%3A+Allow+consumers+to+fetch+from+closest+replica), and available since Kafka 2.4.0.

Comment: Awesome! So its a non-default functionality if i understand correctly right? Kafka will reach to a partition leader per default.

Comment: Yes, by default it uses the LeaderSelector implemention for backward compatibility. Then you also have RackAwareReplicaSelector or you can have your own logic by implementing the ReplicaSelector interface (see the replica.selector.class broker parameter).